# How to send response for iOS apps with OAuth v2.0 server

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using [oauth2-server-php](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/) to create an OAuth 2.0 server.

My question is how do I send a response to a mobile/desktop app after the user has authenticated and allowed access to their app?

In a browser there's a simple redirect that occurs that sends the code back to the program. But there is no way you can redirect to a website if it's a mobile/desktop app.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking around trying to find examples of existing OAuth 2 APIs that handle mobile applications.

The one I found was [Campaign Monitor's API](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/getting-started/#authenticating_with_oauth).

This is their docs:

> These are the steps for authenticating from desktop or other applications.
>
> 1. Direct users of your application to:https://api.createsend.com/oauth?type=user_agent&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&scope=scope
> 2. The user of your application approves (or doesn't approve) your application.
> 3. The user of your application is redirected to the redirect_uri with the following parameters in the hash of the URL:
>
>    https://sender.example.com/integrate#access_token=abc123&expires_in=1209600

Not sure if there's a right or wrong way to go about this but seems to work for them.

Hope that helps somebody.